# Why this simple query fail? select convert(decimal(10,8),111.1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

Working on SQL Server 2005

Why this fail?

```
select convert(decimal(10,8),111.1)
```

and this work ok

```
select convert(decimal(10,8),11.1)
```

and how can I solve?

on my really query I have this value.

convert(decimal(10,8),111.175933837891)

but I checked the problem is 3 Int and  N decimals,
why if i have `decimal(10,8)` this fails?

the error is

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting numeric to data type numeric.

Comment: What is the Error message?

Comment: Which dbms? (ANSI SQL has no convert function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decimal(10,8)` represents a number with 10 digits *total* and 8 digits to the *right* of the decimal point, so the largest number that can be represented is `99.99999999`.  You could use `decimal(10,7)` and sacrifice one digit to the right of the decimal point or use `decimal(11,8)` to add one digit to the left.

To store `111.175933837891` completely you must use a scale of *at least* 12 and a precision that is *at least* 3 more than the scale, so `decimal(15,12)` would be the smallest type that could hold that value without loss of precision.

Comment: because you only have two digits to the left of the decimal point available (`10-8 = 2`)

Answer (score 2):

Because scale is `8` and precision is `10`.

Total no. of digits before decimal point is `precision - scale`

`10-8 = 2` So you can have only `2` digits before `decimal`. But you have 3 digits before decimal in `111.175933837891` so it will throw `Arithmetic overflow error`

you have to increase the `precision` in decimal or decrease `scale` in decimal.

```
select convert(decimal(11,8),111.175933837891)
```